# After upgrading to xcode 3.2.5 can't connect to the network

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I use a C++ library in my application which connects to the network (I suppose it uses sockets). I've been using it for months and I was using xcode 3.2.4. Now, I just had the great idea of upgrading to xcode 3.2.5, and I found out my application was crashing with the error:

If you are encountering this problem running a simulator binary within gdb, make sure you 'set start-with-shell off' first. 3.2.5

Ok, couldn't solve it, so went back to 3.2.4, as suggested somewhere. The application is not crashing anymore, but now the library can't connect anymore to the network. Tried to rebuild it (I didn't write the library but I have the sources) and use the new library, but nothing. Still the library can't connect to the network. I tried with every simulator.

Any idea what there could be wrong and how I may be able to solve this? Can I somehow delete manually everything related to xcode and the simulator and try to start all over again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a version of libCURL that was built for an earlier OS. The solution was to rebuild the library under iOS 4.2 to eliminate the $UNIX2003 symbol decorations. (I wrote up the full details at http://www.creativealgorithms.com/blog/content/building-libcurl-ios-42.)

Comment: It seems the problem has disappeared. Anyway, I have some elements to suppose that rebuilding, like you said, may have solved the problem. Thanks!